# search bar handlebars + mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

when i try search post from words title

the search not work and no posts appear

i don't know if syntax is true

```
Post.find({'post':{title_create:wordSearching}},(err,data)=>{
```

but no error and also no result after searching

searchPost = input

```
const Post = require('../models/PostModel').Post;
      serachPosts:async(req,res)=> {

    const wordSearching= await req.query.searchPost;

  try{
     Post.find({'post':{title_create:wordSearching}},(err,data)=>{
          if(err){
              console.log(err);
          }else{
              res.render('default/singlePostSearch',{data:data});
          }

      })

    }catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
}
```

and this /models/PostModels.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    title_create: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
module.exports = {Post: mongoose.model('post', PostSchema )};
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?I am having a hard time understanding your problem

Comment: @ManosKounelakis i edit my question and i hope is better

Comment: For search functionality you must use regex. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your Search String should exactly match the post:{tittle:String} **

```
 Post.find({'post.title':wordSearching},(err,data)=>{
```

Comment: yah true i just delete 'post' and it's solved thank u a lot

Answer (score 0):

i answer the problem only delete  'post':